# C++ operator overloading

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-construction, operator-overloading

In C#, the method(function) of overloading any operator must be `static` and `public`.

I see that making it `static` is a good thing, every object doesn't need its own version of it.

But in C++, it doesn't have to be `static`. Why does C# enforce this and C++ doesn't?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both designs?

Comment: Operator overloads can be static in C++.

Comment: And even if the operator isn't static it doesn't meen that every object has their own copy of the *code*

Comment: @Neil: I didn't say that it can't be "static", all I'm asking is why the compiler doesn't enfore making it "static" like C#..

Comment: @Andreas: Yeah, I know this. I updated the question.

Comment: @Mavric "in C++, It musn't be static" looks like you DID say that.

Comment: @Neil: I think he means "needs not".

Comment: @Bo Persson Does it have different meanings? Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***why C++ Doesn't enforce operator overloading to be "Static" ?***
If you make overloaded operator function static it wont have access to `this`. One would need access to `this` inside the overloaded function, as usually the function would change the state of `this`.

You can make a overloaded operator function `static` if you don't need access to `this` inside that function, which essentially means you are not manipulating the state of the object on which the operator function was invoked. So it is opssible but not usual or essentially desired.

Making an globally overloaded operator function static would limit the scope of the operator function to the same file.

Given the both above, Compiler doesn't enforce overloaded operator functions to be static since enforcing it would provide no real advantage or convenience, rather not enforcing the same provides more convenience.

***why C# enforces operator overloading to be "Static" ?***
[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx) explains it much better than I can.

***What are the advantages and disadvantages?***
Well, the answer to the first Question does say out when one could make a overloaded operator function static & that explains the advantage/disdvantage.

Comment: I've reconstructed my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why C# enforces overloaded operators to be `static` ?

I'm not one of the C# designer.  A potential reason is that experience with C++ showed that having an asymmetry between the arguments of operators (which is a direct consequence of having member diadic operators) is a bad idea.

> Why C++ doesn't enforce overloaded operators to be `static` ?

Because there was no previous experience to build on and it seemed a good idea? (The distinction doesn't make sense in Algol68, one of the few language predating C++ which had operator overloading.  BTW C++ didn't repeat Algol68 mistakes in operator overloading.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this part "asymmetry between the arguments of operators (which is a direct consequence of having member diadic operators) is a bad idea".

Comment: @mavric, Often you expect operators to be commutative, that is a+b is equivalent to b+a.  If one argument is special (the object for which a member is called) language rules make make the commutativity difficult to achieve.  For instance in C++, implicit conversion will not be available.

Comment: So you are saying that: the compiler enforce it to be static to enforce that every operator overloading method should return a value, not just aler its object data ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Because they're different languages.  I don't really know C#, so I can't
comment on it too much, but in C++, some operators, like `[]` and `()`
(not to mention the copy assignment operator) can't be static, for
various reasons.  And in general, why would you want an operator to be
static?  I don't think I've ever made an operator static in C++.  The
classical binary arithmetic operators are usually free functions, and
all of the other operators members.  (One can argue whether it is better
for `operator++` to be a member or a free function, but the most wide
spread practice seems to be to make them members.)

Answer (score 0):

I think C# enforces it because it makes better sense, not that it would be wrong.
It was hard for me to understand `this` parameter when adding 2 objects, so I think they enforce it to reduce complexity, but there's still nothing wrong with operators being non-static, just easier to understand.